# looping, if statement, and ${#var} skipping?

Tags: shell, if-statement

```
len=`echo "${#jday}"`

if [ "$len"==1 ];
then
new_jday=`echo "00 $jday" | awk '{print $1$2}'`
fi
```

In the above code, I obtain len variable, which is the number of digits in a given integer ($jday), in a loop. These integers have either 1, 2, or 3 digits and for those having only 1 digit, I want to prepend "00" (e.g. if the integer is 1, it should appear as 001). However, when I run the above code, all integers get appended with 00 and I fail to see why that is. When I echo len, I get the correct length (i.e. 1 ,2 or 3). Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I see multiple errors here:

len=`echo "${#jday}"` can be just `len=${#jday}`

`if [ "$len"==1 ]` is wrong, because you need spaces around `==` and also it should be `-eq` because it is integer comparison.

Finally, `new_jday=`echo "00 $jday" | awk '{print $1$2}'`` looks quite ugly. Why not just `new_jday=00$jday`? Try to indicate what is your general input and your desired output and we'll try to find a better way to handle this.

Comment: For numeric formatting try `printf '%03d\n' "${#jday}"`.

Comment: Thanks fedorqui, solved it in a different way without the if statement, which I describe in a later comment. Thanks a lot for your time! and yes Etan Reisner, that's exactly what I used! thanks a bunch!

Comment: @januka you could post your final code as an answer, so that future readers will understand what was missing and what helped to you.

Comment: I already did in a later comment fedorqui! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

'==' is used to compare Strings, try '-eq'

```
if [ "1"==1 ];
then
    echo "1";
fi

if [ "2"==1 ];
then
    echo "2";
fi

if [ "1" -eq 1 ];
then
    echo "1";
fi

if [ "2" -eq 1 ];
then
    echo "2";
fi
```

will output:

```
1
2
1
```

Comment: Thanks evilive, I tried both your suggestions before posting the question but when I use -eq or leave space on either side of ==, I get a constant output 005 irrespective of the input. I was able to solve it for now by including the following line without the if statement. I can use my output if everything is mapped to 3 digits. Thanks again for your time!
new_jday=$(printf "%03d" $jday)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through the if condition, I opted to use printf function to format my integers to 3 digits as follows;

new_jday=$(printf "%03d" $jday)